# Why can't I use a variable in a results.find_all?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a pretty basic web scrape but I'd like to be able to use variables so I don't have to keep repeating code for multiple pages.

example line of code:

```
elems = results.find_all("span", class_="st_2XVIMK7 st_8u0ePN3 st_2oUi2Vb st_3kXJm4P")
```

I would like it to read as:

```
elems = results.find_all(<variable>)
```

and then have my variable be:

```
'"span", class_="st_2XVIMK7 st_8u0ePN3 st_2oUi2Vb st_3kXJm4P"'
```

However, when I do this, I get no results. I've included the rest of the function below. Does anyone know why this will not work?

EDIT:
I've also tried splitting it up like below example but still get the same issue:

```
elems = results.find_all(variable1 , class_=variable2)
variable1 = '"span"'
variable2 = '"st_2XVIMK7 st_8u0ePN3 st_2oUi2Vb st_3kXJm4P"'
```

code:

```
def get_name(sym,result,elem,name):
    url = URL + sym
    page = requests.get(url)


    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find(id=result)
    elems = results.find_all(elem)


    for elem in elems:
        name_elem = elem.find(name)
        print(name_elem.text)



get_name('top',"app",'"span",class_="st_2XVIMK7 st_8u0ePN3 st_2oUi2Vb st_3kXJm4P"','"span","st_3lrv4Jo"')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find_all` method takes more then one parameter
you are just using a string in the first argument of the method which would struggle to find anything

you will need to split the variable into multiple so your variable `'"span", class_="st_2XVIMK7 st_8u0ePN3 st_2oUi2Vb st_3kXJm4P"'` will need to be split into to variables
`elem = "span"`  and `class="st_2XVIMK7 st_8u0ePN3 st_2oUi2Vb st_3kXJm4P"`

and in your code it will look like
`elems = results.find_all(elem, class)`

Just a few more things: 
according to the documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all and what i can find online the class parameter takes a Dict with a string array for multiple class values so your function will look more like 
`findAll(elem, {'class':['st_2XVIMK7', 'st_8u0ePN3', 'st_2oUi2Vb', 'st_3kXJm4P']})`

Comment: I had tried that as well. If you look at the `results = soup.find(id=result)` line, you'll see that i put in the "id=" and then the variable. That was because I was having a similar issue there. Changing the code to something like `elems = results.find_all(elem, class_=clas)`  (where elem = "span" and clas = "st_2XVIMK7 st_8u0ePN3 st_2oUi2Vb st_3kXJm4P") still produces no output

Comment: @whileINside I cant comment directly on your post BUT also the variables need to not have ```"``` in them, ```variable1 = '"span"'``` should just be ```variable1 = 'span'``` and from the documentation to have multiple class variables you need to put them in a dict like so ```{'class':['class1', 'class2']}```